# flutter google places: Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am developing an application using [google map](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) and [google places](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places).

When I call `PlacesAutocomplete.show()`, it gives the following error message. `Null check operator used on a null value`

- pubspec.yaml

  ```
  environment:
     sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

  dependencies:
     google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.5
     flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
     location: ^4.1.1  
     flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  ```
- Call

  ```
  InkWell(
     onTap: () async {
         Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
            context: context,
            apiKey: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
         );
      }, child: Text("SHOW") 
  ),
  ```

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could take a look what might cause the issue?

Comment: I just added InkWell to show Autocomplete screen.

Comment: `types`, `components` and `strictbounds` are required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide all the required and non null parameters of the function .show. Something like that:

> ```
> Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
>       offset: 0,
>       radius: 1000,
>       strictbounds: false,
>       region: "us",
>       language: "en",
>       context: context,
>       mode: Mode.overlay,
>       apiKey: Env.googleapikey,
>       sessionToken: sessionToken,
>       components: [new Component(Component.country, "us")],
>       types: ["(cities)"],
>       hint: "Search City",
>       startText: city == null || city == "" ? "" : city
>     );
> ```